# data for CNN , loading for model

Tags: python, image, file, tensorflow, keras

If this is the organisation of my data how would I load this data in to x_train and y_train to make a keras model

train.zip

The image files for the training set

train.txt

The labels for the training set

test.zip

The image files for the test set

[image]

This is how train.txt looks like

I am fumbled of how I should load this data in to a numpy array so I can make a CNN model

Answer (score 1):

First unzip the train.zip file to **train** folder. Below is the code to load the train data.

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array

traindata=[]
with open("train.txt", 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        tempdata=[]
        values=line.split(" ")
        img = load_img('train/'+values[0])
        img_array = img_to_array(img)
        tempdata.append(img_array)
        tempdata.append(int(values[1]))
        traindata.append(tempdata)
```

Similarly you can load the test data too.

Comment: If you want the **traindata** array to convert to numpy array you can add the following:

Comment: import numpy as np

Comment: traindata_numpy=np.array(traindata)

Comment: its not quite working, but if i give you a link to the kaggle competition , do you mind trying it there?